# Oracle database hints for bulk Insert from DBLink

Tags: oracle, hints, query-hints

I need to insert around 50 tables that have bulk data in them via DBLink. I generally use the statement

```
insert into <table_name> 
select * from <table_name>@DBLink
```

In some cases, it takes too long to insert. What useful database hints can be used in here to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORACLE's` `APPEND` hint

> The APPEND hint tells the optimizer to perform a direct-path insert, which improves the performance of INSERT .. SELECT operations for a number of reasons:
>
> Data is appended to the end of the table, rather than attempting to use existing free space within the table.
>
> Data is written directly to the data files, by-passing the buffer cache.
>
> Referential integrity constraints are not considered. *
>
> No trigger processing is performed. *

Syntax:

```
INSERT /* + APPEND */ INTO YourTable
SELECT * FROM YourTable@DBLink
```